# Debian build the freeradius package with unixodbc support

Tags: sql-server, debian, freeradius, unixodbc

Here is what I am trying to achieve, we want to install freeradius using a Microsoft SQL backend. I read on the internet that we need to achieve this goal using the unixodbc driver.

I am able to set up the unixodbc driver from apt-get and if I configure Freetds to use it. After the installation and configs I can run the test command:

```
isql -v DVSQLServer USERNAME PASSWORD
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

This is actually working. But I found out downloading the freeradius tarbal that it can't use the rlm_sql_unixodbc driver, because in the debian/rules file they compile it using the flag:

```
--without-rlm_sql_unixodbc
```

I thought it would be easy to remove the flag from debian/rules and just build my own package using the command line:

```
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```

But it is failing with error:

```
checking for SQLConnect in -lodbc... no
checking for sql.h... yes
configure: error: set --without-rlm_sql_unixodbc to disable it explicitly.
configure: error: ./configure failed for ./drivers/rlm_sql_unixodbc
configure: error: ./configure failed for src/modules/rlm_sql
make: *** [config.status] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

Do you have any idea of what I am missing to compile it successfully?

I can also tell you that I ran these apt-get command to make sure I was having all the dependencies.

```
apt-get build-dep -y unixodbc freetds-bin freetds-common freetds-dev tdsodbc freeradius
apt-get install -y unixodbc freetds-bin freetds-common freetds-dev tdsodbc libssl-dev dpkg-dev
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After four days of hard work at searching and finding everything needed to build Freeradius with the UnixODBC drivers. I came up with that solution that finally works fine for me. This answer describes every steps I had to go throught to make my Freeradius working with a MSSQL backend using unixodbc on a Debian Squeeze server.

Compiling the Freeradius server

In order to install Freeradius using the MSSQL backend I had to recompile Freeradius using the unixodbc drivers. 
To enable this driver I had to modify the package provided by Freeradius.

Ensure that the source repository are available in the **/etc/apt/sources.list** of the server you are compiling from.
If you are missing them, the error message is: **E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list**

A source URI start by **deb-src**

```
deb http://debian.mirror.rafal.ca/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.mirror.rafal.ca/debian squeeze main contrib non-free # Source URI
deb http://debian.mirror.rafal.ca/debian-security squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://debian.mirror.rafal.ca/debian-security squeeze/updates main contrib non-free # Source URI
```

Before you can compile the freeradius packages you need to install the dependencies of the dependencies:

```
apt-get build-dep -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev freetds-bin quilt freetds-common freetds-dev \
tdsodbc freeradius libiodbc2-dev
```

Install dependencies packages

```
apt-get install -y unixodbc libiodbc2-dev freetds-bin freetds-common freetds-dev tdsodbc \
libssl-dev dpkg-dev quilt libssl-dev libpam0g-dev libmysqlclient-dev libgdbm-dev \
libsasl2-dev libperl-dev libpcap-dev python-dev libsnmp-dev libpq-dev libltdl3-dev snmp
```

Create the following missing symlink

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libodbc.so.1 /usr/lib/libodbc.so
```

Get the freeradius tarball

```
wget ftp://ftp.freeradius.org/pub/freeradius/freeradius-server-2.2.0.tar.gz
tar zxf freeradius-server-2.2.0.tar.gz
cd freeradius-server-2.2.0
```

Edit the debian/rules file

```
vim freeradius-server-2.2.0/debian/rules
```

Replace  the **--without-rlm_sql_unixodbc** (approximatly line 90) by **--with-rlm_sql_unixodbc**

Build the Debian packages

To build the debian package make sure you installed the dependencies, then execute the following command line:

```
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc -d

ls ../

freeradius_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
freeradius-common_2.2.0+git_all.deb
freeradius-dbg_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
freeradius-dialupadmin_2.2.0+git_all.deb
freeradius-iodbc_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
freeradius-krb5_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
freeradius-ldap_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
freeradius-mysql_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
freeradius-postgresql_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
freeradius-utils_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
libfreeradius2_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
libfreeradius-dev_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
```

Now that you successfully built the packages, move to the parent directory and there you should fine all the debian packages you need in order to build the freeradius server with the unixodbc support.

You can install them using the dpkg command line.

```
dpkg -i freeradius_2.2.0+git_i386.deb freeradius-common_2.2.0+git_all.deb freeradius-utils_2.2.0+git_i386.deb \
libfreeradius2_2.2.0+git_i386.deb
```

Once I had install the freeradius packages, I stopped the service.

```
service freeradius stop
```

I tested it using the command line:

```
freeradius -X
```

Then I configured the SQL connection.

I had to configure the unixodbc driver within these three files:

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[MSSQLServer]
Driver          = FreeTDS
Description     = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
Trace           = No
ServerName      = MSSQLServer
Database        = radius
port            = 1433
tds_version     = 7.0
language        = us_english
```

**/etc/odbcinst.ini**

```
[FreeTDS]
Description     = TDS driver (MS SQL)
Driver          = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

**/etc/freetds/freetds.conf**

```
[MSSQLServer]
    host = mssqlserver.example.com
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
```

Test the connection using the isql command line

```
isql -v MSSQLServer your_db_username 'your_db_password'

# what you should see
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

Now is the time to configure Freeradius to use this unixodbc.

Here are the changes I made in the sql.conf file to make it work.

**/etc/freeradius/sql.conf**

```
database = "mssql"

#
#  Which FreeRADIUS driver to use.
#
driver = "rlm_sql_unixodbc"

# Connection info:
server = "MSSQLServer"
login = "your_db_username"
password = "your_db_password"

# Database table configuration for everything except Oracle
radius_db = "radius"

$INCLUDE sql/${database}/dialup.conf
```

Before continuing create the **/etc/freeradius/sql/mssql/** folder to hold the **dialup.conf** file for MSSQL.

```
mkdir -p /etc/freeradius/sql/mssql/
```

I had to take the **dialup.conf** file from the **freeradius-mysql_2.2.0+git_i386.deb** packages.

Once you have copied the file from the freeradius-mysql package copy it here **/etc/freeradius/sql/mssql/dialup.conf**.

To get it to work with MSSQL, edit the file and replace all the **<< 32** by a **convert(bigint, value)**

```
# MySQL version
'%{%{Acct-Input-Gigawords}:-0}'  << 32

# MSSQL modified version
convert(bigint, '%{%{Acct-Input-Gigawords}:-0}')
```

Save your file and that should be it. If you don't have the MSSQL schema please look at freeradius wiki. http://wiki.freeradius.org/config/MS%20SQL%20DDL%20script

I had an issue with the **AcctStopTime** column it was trying to insert a **NULL** inside it so I changed the default column type.

```
alter table radius.dbo.radacct
alter column AcctStopTime datetime null;
```

After that you can try again launching freeradius and it should collect the data in MSSQL.

```
freeradius -X
```

Regards

Comment: `/usr/lib/libobdc.so` is part of the package `unixodbc-dev`. Since you don't install it, it doesn't get created.

Comment: I didn't installed it because it conflicts with the package libiodbc2-dev. I am getting this error all the time if I do:`The following packages will be REMOVED:
      unixodbc-dev
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libiodbc2-dev`
That is the reason why I was creating the symlink by hand. If you have another way to to do it, I would be very happy to learn it.

Comment: Not saying I have a way, was just pointing it out. Normally when packages conflict like that, you can substitute one for the other and they should work, but it depends on the software in question.

Comment: sir in 2012 microsoft didn't introduce mssql for linux. in 2018 when we are able to install microsoft in ubunto.. can it not be as simple as it is for mysql.. have you tried it? im strugling for it.. plz do tell me if you have a simple way than this....

Comment: I haven't install freeradius with mssql in a very long time, but it is true that microsoft now publishes more software to help the open source community. I would first start looking in the following documentation on how to install mssql odbc driver on ubuntu 16.04. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server#ubuntu-1604. Once install I would try to make the same configuration as described here. Good luck and if you succeed please update this answer.